# Why does my plugin give this error when I initialize it? Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'counter'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, include, initialization, typeerror

I don't understand why I am getting this error?!?! I am trying to use a simple counter plugin for jQuery:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'counter'
```

I have included the plugin file... I can see it in the source

```
/templates/ja_wall/js/counter.js
```

But every time I try to initialize the plugin like so... I get the uncaught TypeError

```
$("#main_counter").counter();
```

I've moved the plugin include up and down the page... Just before the closing head tag... At the bottom of the page... It didn't seem to change anything.... I also have moved my initialization code to a doc ready & a window.load section... Neither worked :-/

Am I missing something obvious? I have other plugins that are doing just fine?!?!

Thanks

Comment: site is using `noConflict` and you have multiple versions of jQuery loading. Only load one and use the new noConflict object for all code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$("#main_counter").kCounter()`.  `jQuery.fn` is not extended with `counter`, only with `kCounter`.